# List of Javascript variable properties

Tags: html, javascript, css, properties

Where can i find a list of all available methods on variables in Javascript?

Eg:

```
var Variable1 = document.getElementById("Button1");
var Variable2 = document.getElementById("Label1");
var Variable3 = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
```

What are the properties of Variable1, Variable2 and Variable3?

Are they the same even though Variable1 is a Button element, Variable2 is a Label element and Variable3 is a TextBox element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from Dredel's answer, you can also log in your console the available properties, and methods of the object by using `console.dir(document.getElementById('idhere'));`, or variations thereof.

Comment: I was able to use your suggestion as well Daedalus.

Answer (score 2):

you can do a `for(var a in obj)` and get a list of everything that the object has in it.
In your case `for(a in Variable1)` will reveal all the objects. You can then look at them (in the loop) via `Variable1[a]`

And they will be largely the same, assuming they're part of the DOM cause DOM objects all inherit from the same display object, but no, they won't be identical since certain HTML objects have unique properties that aren't shared globally.  Be prepared for a LONG list!

Comment: Thanks @Dredel.. I got the LONG list..!

Answer (score 2):

MDN is a good reference. Begin with [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node) and [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element), from which pretty much every HTML element will inherit.

Another good way to learn that are the DOM references: HTML Level 2 [IDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/idl-definitions.html) and [JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/ecma-script-binding.html) definitions.

There are also some other definitions at the [HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) itself.

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(variable1)
```

This will return only *own* properties, not inherited ones. If you want all of them use `for (var property in obj) ...`.

Elements all inherit from the same objects, so they mostly have the same properties; you'll find differences like `.checked`, `.multiple`, etc.